# JasperReports page footer only printed on last page

Tags: printing, reporting, jasper-reports, ireport

For some reason my page footer with the date and page x/y gets only printed on the very last page. Does anyone have an idea why?

I am using `JasperReports 3.1.2` and `iReport 3.0.0`.

**EDIT**: just for the record: it worked after I moved two subreports and two page breaks from the `Title` band to the `Detail` band. Don't know why I put them there, but now it works..

Answer (score 4):

You can select which band to add. just use page footer instead last page footer. Last page footer is used when you want something to be printed at last, but the contain is so  much that it overflows to many pages.

Answer (score 2):

Most probably you are using the `Last Page Footer' band, instead of the 'Page Footer' band.

Comment: Can you share more information about the scenario? Does it always happen or just for cetain report? simplified .jrxml, etc.